# unable to locate element using xpath in htmlunitdriver

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

```
public void Testcase(HashMap<String,String> testDataMap, WebDriver driver) throws Exception {

    if ((testDataMap.get("Browser").equals("HtmlUnitDriver"))) {

        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        Static_wait_Time.IdealWait_Time();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span));
```

Comment: Error  : Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using xpath1
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: please edit your code to include the relevant HTML, as well as your `xpath1` variable declaration

Comment: there is no relevant html to identify the element . Only way is by xpath . Can you please help me

Comment: @lokkeshkrishna well, we need to see HTML code that you are trying to build xpath for, thats what @sircapsalot meant when he asked for relevant HTML.
Another thing is that your code syntax is incorrect. The last line should be `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span"));`

Comment: @sen4ik, thanks ..yeah its my bad ..i have pasted wrong syntax..

Comment: HTML code will be as follows: <span class="dek">First Name &amp;<br>Last Name</span>

Comment: We can't fix the xpath expression unless you paste the full HTML from the page you're trying to work with.

Comment: i have rechecked my code .. its working successfully when other applications(like Google) elements xpaths are provided . But facing issue only with our application. Any suggestions?